# How I can validate my string (bracket) - Android?

Tags: java, android

I have a `String` for example I have :

```
String A = "[name:jim,phone:1254]";
```

And often my `String` is :

```
String A = "[]";
if(A.contentEquals("[]")){
   //do here
}else{
   //do here
}
```

How I can validate my `String`.

Comment: Whatever you did it should work also you can split your String with this `[` and check if you got `]` do something else do other things

Comment: I need to another responses .

Comment: `[]` is always present in your string? If that's the case, you can just use `A.length`

Comment: use String.matches(Regex) to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way can be

```
A = A.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
if(A.equals("")){
   //do here if its empty
}else{
   //do here if it contains value
}
```

***Edit***

As Jokab suggested in the comment, here is more secured way to avoid NPE (Null Pointer Exception).

```
A = A.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
    if("".equals(A)){
       //do here if its empty
    }else{
       //do here if it contains value
    }
```

Comment: Just a note here: doing `"".equals(A)` is always better than doing `A.equals("")` since `""` can never be `null`. If `A == null`, the application will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 2):

```
String A= A.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");

if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(A)) {

    // do if string not empty

}else {

    //do if string empty

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
String A = "[name:jim,phone:1254]";     
  if(A.matches("\\[\\]")){
       //do here if empty
  }else{
      //do here something
  }
```

Comment: Even when ignoring the formatting mistake, this answer suffers from a serious lack of explanation. "code-only" answers are considered very low quality. Please edit to improve by explaining why/how this solves the problem.